# Angular: ¿como eliminar los datos repetidos de un array?

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, map

**Contexto**

Tengo una lista de servicios que estoy extrayendo en un array, pero hay datos que vienen repetidos como se muestra en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo el siguiente código para filtrar el array obtener la lista de servicios:

//Peticion que obtiene los servicios y mapea el objeto para extraer el array

```
getGroupService() {
    this.bookingService.getDoctorById("5d24476eea8ebc659106657c").pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((res: profileAffiliate) => {
        this.virtual = res.affiliate.groupedServices.virtual.map(service => service.service.name.es)
        this.encasa = res.affiliate.groupedServices.atHome.map(service => service.service.name.es)
        this.clinica = res.affiliate.groupedServices.clinic.map(service => service.service.name.es)
        //console.log('clinica', this.clinica);
        console.log(this.virtual, this.encasa, this.clinica);
      })
  }
```

// Método que abre el modal y verifica si el array donde esta almacenado el array groupedServices
// esta vacio

```
 openServiceModal() {
    if (this.groupedServices.length > 0) {

      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SelectServiceModalComponent, {
        data: { services: this.groupedServices, selected: this.services.value ?? [] },
        panelClass: 'DialogContainer'
      });

      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(selectedServices => {
        console.log('The dialog was closed', selectedServices);
        if (selectedServices) {
          this.services.setValue(selectedServices)
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      this.openSnackBar();
    }

  }
```

//Modal, donde filtro (busqueda) los servios

```
selectedServices: any[] = [];
  //array donde almaceno el elemento
  filteredServices: any[] = [];
  services: any[] = [];
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filteredServices = this.services;

    this.search.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe((val: string) => {
      console.log(val);
      if (val == "") {
        this.filteredServices = this.services;
      }
      else {

      }

      this.filteredServices = this.services.filter((x: string) => {
        return x.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase());
      });


      console.log('selectedServices :>> ', this.selectedServices);
      console.log('filteredServices :>> ', this.filteredServices);
      console.log('services :>> ', this.services);
    })
  }
```

La respuesta del json al filtrar los datos, quien filtra y obtiene el arreglo es this.services = data.services;. Tambien adjunto el modelo de datos https://github.com/IzliaB/json
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo elimianr los datos repetidos?

Comment: Puedes adjuntar el `JSON` de la respuesta?

Comment: solo mostras como dato any[]---> y no das el modelo de datos  solo se puede suponer en un array de objetos hay muchas formas de quitar los duplicados por ejemplo por id const arr = [
{id:1 ,name:'uno'}, 
   
{id: 2, name: 'dos'}, 
{id:4 ,name :'cuatro'},
{id:1,name:'uno',repitido:true},
{id:4,name:'cuatro',repitido:true}
]

const ids = arr.map(o => o.id)
const filtered = arr.filter(({id}, index) => !ids.includes(id, index + 1))

console.log(filtered)

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera aqui te dejo el json, muchas gracias por responderme, aqui lo adjunto: https://github.com/IzliaB/json

Comment: @nestdan Hola! Gracias por responderme, actualice la pregunta, no se si asi es correcto, igual me dices. En la funcionalidad de lo que hago: Primero filtro los servicios y los almaceno en this.groupedService. Cuando ya estan almacenados los filtro y los coloco en el modal, te dejo algo de la logic aaqui: https://github.com/IzliaB/json/blob/main/home.component.ts 

Lo que no termino de entender es como puedo eliminar repetidos, no me queda claro en tu ejemplo. Una disculpa si me cuesta darme a entender, Gracias!!

Comment: ante tu pregunta como eliminar datos repetidos en un array el ejemplo muestra como hacerlo por id pero tu estructura es compleja la miro y si encuentro algo te digo saludos

Comment: por ejemplo la respuesta que te dieron sobre usar Set() te es de utilidad?

Comment: @nestdan Si! me fue de muchisima ayuda, aunque no se porque cuando se le da seleccion te trae repetidas las selecciones. Es decir en el modal, ya no lo muestra repetido, pero en la lista de selección, si. Te dejo como se ve: https://github.com/IzliaB/json/blob/main/image.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `set()` para obtener solo los datos no duplicados.

```js
let services = [
"Consultas",
"Médicos",
"Médicos",
"Médicos",
"Médicos",
"Consultas",
"Consultas",
"Médicos",
"Médicos",
]


let servicesLimpio = Array.from(new Set(services))
console.log({servicesLimpio})
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre sencillamente haciendo un loop en el que empieces a discriminar los elementos identicos

Te proporciono un script muy sencillo que hace la tarea que buscas la idea seria que solo lo adaptaras

```
var list = [];
list.push({ id : 1, Text  : "Consultas Medicas" });
list.push({ id : 2, Text  : "Consultas Medicas" });
list.push({ id : 3, Text  : "Servicio" });

// Valor de búsqueda
let search = 'Consultas';
// Listado de resultado
var result = [];

// Ciclo por cada elemento del catalogo
list.forEach(function(elemento, indice, array) {
    // Discriminación de elementos iguales
    if( result.find(p=>p.Text.toLowerCase() == elemento.Text.toLowerCase()) == undefined)
    {
        result.push(elemento);
    }
})

// Resultado
 result.forEach(function(elemento, indice, array) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += elemento.Text + ",";
  });
```

Saludos y que Dios te bendiga